# How to get minimum and maximum value from array list C#

Tags: c#

So i know how to calculate the avg but i dont know how to calculate the min and max value. I'm pretty sure you need to use a for loop but i don't know how to.

```
 public Int32 Average
{
    get
    {
        clsSimpleDataConnection Datalayer = new clsSimpleDataConnection();
        List<Int32> saleslist = new List<Int32>();
        saleslist = Datalayer.LoadIntegerList();
        Int32 AnItem;
        Int32 Total = 0;
        Int32 average;
        Int32 itemcount;
        itemcount = saleslist.Count;
        Int32 index = 0;

        while (index < itemcount)
        {
            AnItem = saleslist[index];
            Total = Total + AnItem;
            index++;

        }
            average = Total / itemcount;
        return average;


    }
}
```

How would i edit this so that it would calculate the min and max?

Comment: `int min = saleslist.Min(); int max = saleslist.Max();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Obviously OP wants to do thin self.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: obviously OP either doesn't know these methods or doesn't want to use them.

Comment: @David. Show what you have done so far to find min or max. We're not here just to write the code for you. DO something and maybe we can help fix any minor errors you encounter

Comment: You start with the 'identity element' or 'neutral element': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element

Comment: @David, check MS source code [Min](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1413), [Max](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1624)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myList = new List<int>();
var min = myList.Min();
var max = myList.Max();
```

Or if you want to use a loop
so for max

```
int max = int.MinValue;
foreach (var type in myList)
{
    if (type > max)
    {
        max = type;
    }
}
```

and for min

```
int min = int.MaxValue;
foreach (var type in myList)
{
    if (type < min)
    {
        min= type;
    }
}
```